# Vue.js iterate a list of objects and display on <a> tag

Tags: vue.js, loops, object

I am trying to iterate a list of the object, and show their attributes to the  tag

For example:

```
<a href="link.url" target="_blank"><i class="links.fontawsomeicon" alt="link.text"></i>link.url</a>
```

Here is my code

```
<div class= "links">
     <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-github" alt="github"></i>GitHub</a>
     <a href="https://instagram.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram" alt=""></i>Instagran</a>
 </div>

<script>
export default{
  name:"displayLinks",
  props:{
  links:Array,
 }
}
```

I know about

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" class= "links">
```

but I am not sure how
to use it in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the link url to the `href` attribute using `v-bind:` :

```
<div v-for="(link, index) in links" :key="index" class= "links">
  <a v-bind:href="link.url" target="_blank">
<i v-bind:class="link.fontawsomeicon" v-bind:alt="link.text"></i>{{link.url}}</a>
</div>
```